# Distance between ios devices using bluetooth 4.0 LE and passing message across paired devices

Tags: objective-c, ios6, bluetooth-lowenergy

i am working on an app which requires finding out distance between ios devices using BT 4.0 LE and then pass a message to paired devices if they are in range. Is there any feasible solution for it??? Please help me out on this

Comment: I'm stuck on the message sending part as well. Did you figure anything out?

Comment: i m able to send messages via peer picker using gamekit framework and as far as i hv searched, u need to implement your custom peer picker to do dis with multiple devices at a time.....!! I hope it helps...!

Answer (score 0):

You cous use RSSI as an indication of distance (more accurately Quality of the current RF condition with that device) and come up with your own mechanism to compuet the distance.

Comment: i tried doing that but RSSI values fluctuate unanimously and i m not getting any specific mechanism for it...!